# How to auto scroll down - Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm developing a new app, where I'm using a ListBox to show exchange messages, but I'm trying to make a automatic scroll down and it isn't working at all.

```
  private void listBoxTrace_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxTrace.SelectedIndex = listBoxTrace.Items.Count - 1;
        listBoxTrace.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

I'm a huge beginner in C#, so I need your help :)

Thanks!

Comment: You should set the SelectedIndex or the TopIndex properties after you have added new Items to the ListBox, for sure not in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: Comment out `listBoxTrace.SelectedIndex = -1;`  Move the code to where you are adding items to the ListBox.